# How to call a script on success of $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

### The goal

Call a script (to be more specific, qTip2 script) on success of `$.ajax` function from jQuery.

### The problem

I have the following script to work with KnockoutJS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/ProductsSummary/List?output=json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var mappingOptions = {
            create: function (options) {
                return (new (function () {
                    this.finalMeasure = ko.computed(function () {
                        return this.quantity() > 1 ? this.measure() + "s"
                        : this.measure();
                    }, this);

                    this.infoComposition = ko.computed(function () {
                        return this.quantity() + ' ' + this.finalMeasure();
                    }, this);

                    ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
                })());
            }
        };

        ViewModel.Summary.products = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
        ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);

        $("ul.products-list li").each(function () {
            var $productId = $(this).data("productid"),
                $match = $(".summary")
                         .find("li[data-productid=" + $productId + "]")
                             .length > 0;

            if ($match) {
                $(this).find("button.action").addClass("remove");
            } else {
                $(this).find("button.action").addClass("add");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In the following fragment, I set a class to a button to define its style, but I have no success because I need to call the qTip2 again to render the new tooltip. See:

```
$("ul.products-list li").each(function () {
    var $productId = $(this).data("productid"),
        $match = $(".summary")
                 .find("li[data-productid=" + $productId + "]")
                     .length > 0;

    if ($match) {
        $(this).find("button.action").addClass("remove");
    } else {
        $(this).find("button.action").addClass("add");
    }
});
```

To make the things work, I have to call the qTip2 script after this fragment, but it was previously called.

To do not be redundant or practice the *DRY concept*, how can I call, inside of the "on success", qTip2 script again?

### A little of code

My qTip2 Script:

```
$(function () {
        var targets = $("ul.products-list li .controls
                      button.action.add").attr('oldtitle', function () {
            var title = $(this).attr('title');
            return $(this).removeAttr('title'), title;
        }),

            shared_config = {
                content: {
                    text: function (event, api) {
                        return $(event.currentTarget).attr('oldtitle');
                    }
                },
                position: {
                    viewport: $(window),
                    my: "bottom center",
                    at: "top center",
                    target: "event"
                },
                show: {
                    target: targets
                },
                hide: {
                    target: targets
                },
                style: "qtip-vincae qtip-vincae-green"
            };

        $('<div/>').qtip(shared_config);

        $('<div/>').qtip($.extend(true, shared_config, {
            content: {
                text: function (event, api) {
                    var target = $(event.currentTarget),
                        content = target.data("tooltipcontent");

                    if (!content) {
                        content = target.next("div:hidden");
                        content && target.data("tooltipcontent", content);
                    }

                    return content || false;
                }
            },
            position: {
                my: "top center",
                at: "bottom center",
                viewport: $(".content"),
                container: $(".content")
            },
            show: {
                event: "click",
                effect: function () {
                    $(this).show(0, function () {
                        $(this).find("input[name=productQuantity]").focus();
                    });
                }
            },
            hide: {
                event: "click unfocus",
                fixed: false
            },
            events: {
                hide: function (event, api) {
                    $($(this).find("input[type=text].quantity")).val("");
                    $($(this).find("button")).prop("disabled", true);
                }
            },
            style: "qtip-vincae qtip-vincae-grey"
        }));
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you should call simply `$(this).find("button.action").qtip()`  or `.qtip(...)` and set/update what you want.
This demo could be your cheat-sheet:
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#validation

Comment: Oh! Thanks about your answer. The problem is: I have customized tooltips that was defined by classes, and I think that `.qtip()` in an element is not enough. Do you have another suggestion, maybe?

Comment: Have you tried this? qtip jquery plugin has only 1 function you can call and that is `qtip(...)`. I'm not sure about your customization, if it is css only, then it should change without calling anything.

Comment: I'm even less sure about the problem. The button's class is not changing and that is all you want to make work? I would guess this `button.action` selector is not working, because the button is not in the `ul.products-list li`. You are not using the css class in the custom code, so it doesn't matter when you change the class. (to be fair I'm just guessing, I'm not too familier with qtip)

Comment: Basically I just want to change the class — and I can do it. The problem is: the change of the class doesn't make effect because qTip2 is called before the change. In other words, I have to "re"call the qTip2 script.

Comment: Then call `qtip()` again (as the documentation says), but if the button is rendered by the qtip script then you won't have the class on the button after calling it again... 
Also adding a class to an element in JS should take action immediately. You can select the elements added by the qtip script too, which should change the look of them. Are you saying that the css class is on the button, if you debug it, but there is no change in the style? In that case probably another css class is overriding the style in the newly added class. You could demonstrate the issue with http://jsfiddle.net ...

Comment: Imagine a web store with products list and shopping cart. Each product have its own "add button" ***if*** it is not already on the shopping list. What I'm doing is exactly this: I check if the product exists on the shopping list; if yes, then the button's class is "remove" because I will remove it from the list; if no, then the button's class is "add" because I will add it to the list. The problem is: I'm rendering the products of shopping cart with AJAX and in the same moment I need to check the products integrity with the list. Can you understand now? Isn't about styles, but jQuery *timing*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32703/discussion-between-balint-bako-and-chiefgui)